# Convert android drawable into xamarin.forms ImageSource

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an API binded to Xamarin.Android part of project, that returns image as Drawable object. I need to show this image in UI, that is written in Xamarin.Forms. The problem is that Image control there accepts only ImageSource as a source.
How can I wrap Drawable into ImageSource object?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
byte[] bytes = drawable.ToArray();
var iamgeSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

Comment: I have try this and it seem to dont work with AdaptiveIconDrawable. I have asked a question for this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137503/xamarin-forms-list-app-with-icon-android-only